# "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda"

Tags: boot, partitioning

I am a beginner and not an expert on tech.
I tried to get Ubuntu on USB key using this video I found:
https://youtu.be/g1tZ7X0U-8c

When it was almost done installing on the target usb I got this error message:
"Unable to install GRUB in dev/sda
Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed.
This is a fatal error."

Then after I closed the message and it kinda glitched out and then I got the installation complete message.

When it restarted I removed the Source USB key when prompted.

Then I got this message from my computer:
"Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed.
Insert Recovery Media and Hit any key
Then Select 'Boot Manager' to choose a new Boot Devie or to Boot Recovery Media"

When I hit enter there was no bootable device in the boot manager.

Obviously I did something wrong but I have no idea what it was.
Also the only thing I did different from the video was set up an efi partition.
If anyone could help or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you included an ESP -  efi system partition on external drive, you made a good choice. You just now need to use live installer, add Boot-Repair ppa and install grub using advanced mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  If UEFI, be sure to boot live intaller in UEFI mode as that is how it will repair. Original issues is old bug. Please post that it applies to you. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Answer (score 0):

First: Enter Bios menu and see if your hard drive is located or not, and read it's detail to sure about the space if you found it, if you didn't find it make sure the STAT cable is connected to the hard drive and make sure that it's working, damage cable will case ATA error, system can't reach data on Device, also Bios will not read it right.

Note: If you are using a PC and the new SATA cable didn't work so The whole of the power supply need to replace.

Second: Make sure that the hard disk has installed system , you can load Ubuntu from the USB or CD , then choose try Ubuntu without install and when it load open Disks program from the programs menu and check if the hard is located and if it contain a filesystem partition or not.

If you cant find Filesystem partition so Install Ubuntu on the hard disk, But if you found A system partition use [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)  to fix the system files.